# Problems understanding keras logging output

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Training my model model with

```
 model.fit_generator(
    ...,
    verbose=1,
    ...
)
```

generates the following output:

```
Epoch 1/5
64 128
128 192

  64/6400 [..............................] - ETA: 466s - loss: 0.0189 - mean_squared_error: 0.0189192 256

 128/6400 [..............................] - ETA: 253s - loss: 0.0163 - mean_squared_error: 0.0163
```

what does

```
 64 128
128 192
```

mean? It certainly has to do with the batch_size of 64, but what do these specific output lines represent and why are they printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case when you set the `verbose=1` option - Keras is printing the information about `loss`, estimated epoch time remaining and a metrics provided during model compilation after each batch. Usually it's printed dynamically - so you could only see a one bar for each epoch - but for some reason your `Python` is printing it new line batch after batch.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for your answer. But there seems to be a misunderstanding - I was asking about two specific lines, with only numbers. I have edited my question, to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find my own "error": There is a print statement in my generator.